# Problem understanding code from C++: Concurrency in Action

Tags: c++, multithreading, quicksort

I'm studying Concurrency in Action (first edition, C++11) and I have some problems understanding part of code from chapter 8, page 228, in which the autor shows a multithreaed-version of QuickSort in the context of dividing data recursively.

The whole code  is:

```
template<typename T>
struct sorter
{
    struct chunk_to_sort
    {
        std::list<T> data;
        std::promise<std::list<T> > promise;
    };

    thread_safe_stack<chunk_to_sort> chunks;  //this is a thread-safe stack explained somewhere else
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    unsigned const max_thread_count;
    std::atomic<bool> end_of_data;

    sorter():
        max_thread_count(std::thread::hardware_concurrency()-1),
        end_of_data(false)
    {}

    ~sorter()
    {
        end_of_data=true;
        for(unsigned i=0;i<threads.size();++i)
        {
            threads[i].join();
        }
    }

    void try_sort_chunk()
    {
        boost::shared_ptr<chunk_to_sort > chunk=chunks.pop();
        if(chunk)
        {
        sort_chunk(chunk);
        }
    }

    std::list<T> do_sort(std::list<T>& chunk_data)
    {
        if(chunk_data.empty())
        {
            return chunk_data;
        }
        std::list<T> result;
        result.splice(result.begin(),chunk_data,chunk_data.begin());
        T const& partition_val=*result.begin();

        typename std::list<T>::iterator divide_point=
            std::partition(chunk_data.begin(),chunk_data.end(),
                           [&](T const& val){return val<partition_val;});

        chunk_to_sort new_lower_chunk;
        new_lower_chunk.data.splice(new_lower_chunk.data.end(),
                                    chunk_data,chunk_data.begin(),
                                    divide_point);

        std::future<std::list<T> > new_lower=
            new_lower_chunk.promise.get_future();
        chunks.push(std::move(new_lower_chunk));
        if(threads.size()<max_thread_count)
        {
            threads.push_back(std::thread(&sorter<T>::sort_thread,this));
        }

        std::list<T> new_higher(do_sort(chunk_data));

        result.splice(result.end(),new_higher);
        while(new_lower.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(0)) !=
              std::future_status::ready)
        {
            try_sort_chunk();
        }

        result.splice(result.begin(),new_lower.get());
        return result;
    }

    void sort_chunk(boost::shared_ptr<chunk_to_sort > const& chunk)
    {
        chunk->promise.set_value(do_sort(chunk->data));
    }

    void sort_thread()
    {
        while(!end_of_data)
        {
            try_sort_chunk();
            std::this_thread::yield();
        }
    }
};

template<typename T>
std::list<T> parallel_quick_sort(std::list<T> input)
{
    if(input.empty())
    {
        return input;
    }
    sorter<T> s;
    return s.do_sort(input);
}
```

**The part I do not get the logic of** is inside the function template do_sort, that is:

```
    chunk_to_sort new_lower_chunk;
    new_lower_chunk.data.splice(new_lower_chunk.data.end(),
                                chunk_data,chunk_data.begin(),
                                divide_point);

    std::future<std::list<T> > new_lower=
        new_lower_chunk.promise.get_future();
    chunks.push(std::move(new_lower_chunk));
    if(threads.size()<max_thread_count)
    {
        threads.push_back(std::thread(&sorter<T>::sort_thread,this));
    }

    std::list<T> new_higher(do_sort(chunk_data));

    result.splice(result.end(),new_higher);
    while(new_lower.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(0)) !=
          std::future_status::ready)
    {
        try_sort_chunk();
    }

    result.splice(result.begin(),new_lower.get());
    return result;
```

I get the single instructions.
I do not get the whole picture, namely how and where the data are recursively divided and ordered by different threads.

Comment: Could you clarify more, what specifically you don't understand. That are still a lot of statements in that extracted snippet, and you can't seriously expect from us to explicitely explain all of them. So please focus more to those you cannot grasp specifically. [Edit] your quesiton by adding that information please.

Comment: I edited the question as πάντα ῥεῖ suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code uses `std::partition` to divide the data into two parts: those less than the partition value, and those not less than the partition value.

Then it uses the `splice` member function of `std::list` to move the nodes that are less than the partition value into a new list, and adds it to the list of chunks to sort. It spawns a new thread if there are less than the maximum number of threads running.

Then the code recursively sorts the remaining list: those items not less than the partition value. This may in turn spawn more threads.

Finally, while the list of values less than the partition value has not been processed, this thread then processes the pending chunks itself.